# Problem with cross compilation of a c program on a host machine (amd64 architecture) for a target machine (Beagleplay, aarch64 architecture)

Tags: cross-compiling, gtk3, arm64

I tried to cross compile a GUI program written in C. It uses the GTK library.
The target machine is a BeaglePlay board whose architecture is aarch64. The host machine is an Ubuntu 22.04 running in WSL. Its architecture is amd64.
The source code is as follows:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

GtkWidget *test_stack;
GtkWidget *label1;
GtkWidget *label2;
GtkWidget *label3;
GtkWidget *label4;
gint cycle_tracker = 0;
void end_program (GtkWidget *wid, gpointer ptr)
{
    gtk_main_quit ();
}

static void go_back (GtkButton *button)
{
  g_print ("Go back.\n");
  GtkStack *stack = GTK_STACK (test_stack);
  const gchar *visible_child_name = gtk_stack_get_visible_child_name (stack);
  gint i = 0;
  i = atoi(visible_child_name);
  g_print("Current page: %d\n",i);
  if(i == 0){
    return;
  }
  else{
    i=i-1;
  }
  //char *new_page;
  char new_page[2] = {0};
  sprintf(new_page,"%d",i);
  gtk_stack_set_visible_child_name(stack,new_page);
  g_print("New page: %s\n",new_page);
}

static void go_forward (GtkButton *button)
{
    g_print ("Go forward.\n");
    GtkStack *stack = GTK_STACK (test_stack);
    const gchar *visible_child_name = gtk_stack_get_visible_child_name (stack);
    gint i = 0;
    i = atoi(visible_child_name);
    g_print("Current page: %d\n",i);
    if(i >= 3){
        return;
    }
    else{
        i=i+1;
    }
    //char *new_page;
    char new_page[2] = {0};
    sprintf(new_page,"%d",i);
    gtk_stack_set_visible_child_name(stack,new_page);
    g_print("New page: %s\n",new_page);
}

static void go_back_d (GtkButton *button)
{}

static void go_forward_d (GtkRadioButton *radio_button)
{
    g_print ("Go forward. Dynamic page editing.\n");
    
    cycle_tracker = 0;
    GtkLabel *casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label1);
    const gchar *radio_button_label;
    radio_button_label = gtk_button_get_label ((GtkButton *)radio_button);
    if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option1") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label1);
        cycle_tracker = 1;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option2") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label1);
        cycle_tracker = 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option3") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label1);
        cycle_tracker = 3;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option4") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label2);
        cycle_tracker = 4;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option5") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label2);
        cycle_tracker = 5;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option6") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label2);
        cycle_tracker = 6;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option7") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label3);
        cycle_tracker = 7;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option8") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label3);
        cycle_tracker = 8;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option9") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label3);
        cycle_tracker = 9;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option10") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label4);
        cycle_tracker = 10;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option11") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label4);
        cycle_tracker = 11;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label,"option12") == 0){
        casted_label = GTK_LABEL (label4);
        cycle_tracker = 12;
    }
    else if(strcmp(radio_button_label," ") == 0){
        g_print ("ERROR!!!\n");
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
    g_print("Current cycle: %d\n",cycle_tracker);
    gchar label_text[6] = "";
    sprintf(label_text,"page%d",cycle_tracker);
    gtk_label_set_text (casted_label,label_text);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new ();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "test_window.glade", NULL);
    GtkWidget *win = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "test_window");

    GtkWidget *back_btn = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "back");
        GtkWidget *next_btn = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "next");
        GtkWidget *quit_btn = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "quit");

        test_stack = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "test_stack");

    GtkWidget *option1 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option1");
    GtkWidget *option2 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option2");
    GtkWidget *option3 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option3");
    GtkWidget *option4 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option4");
    GtkWidget *option5 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option5");
    GtkWidget *option6 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option6");
    GtkWidget *option7 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option7");
    GtkWidget *option8 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option8");
    GtkWidget *option9 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option9");
    GtkWidget *option10 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option10");
    GtkWidget *option11 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option11");
    GtkWidget *option12 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "option12");

    label1 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "label1");
    label2 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "label2");
    label3 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "label3");
    label4 = (GtkWidget *) gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "label4");
    
    g_signal_connect (back_btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (go_back), NULL);
        g_signal_connect (next_btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (go_forward), NULL);
        g_signal_connect (quit_btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (end_program), NULL);

    g_signal_connect (option1, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (option2, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (option3, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);

    g_signal_connect (option4, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (option5, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (option6, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);

    g_signal_connect (option7, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (option8, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (option9, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);

    g_signal_connect (option10, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (option11, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (option12, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (go_forward_d), NULL);


    gtk_widget_show_all (win);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

I used the following command for the cross-compilation:

```bash
aarch64-none-linux-gnu-gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` test_window.c -o test_window_cross `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

The cross-compiler returned the following errors:
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtk-3
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk-3
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lpango-1.0
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lharfbuzz
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -latk-1.0
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo-gobject
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lcairo
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/home/debian/toolchains/gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-linux-gnu/11.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I was expecting a successful compilation of my program. I have used the same toolchain to compile a hello world program for the same target machine and it compiled successfully. I also ran the compiled program on the target machine and it worked. What could be wrong with this program I trying to compile or the command I am using to compile?